# What's causing these weird creases in my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, edges

(Searched around here and couldn't find an answer)

I'm attempting to create new edges from these two selected vertices, but when I do, I'm getting these strange creases that deform the mesh in undesirable ways. I've tried removing doubles but that made no difference. How can I prevent this from happening? [image]

Comment: hello, maybe recalculate the normals? if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Oh, wow. I recalculated normals and that totally worked. Never had to use that feature before, so I never considered looking to that. Thanks for the tip!